# CSV File line data to dictionary input formatting

Tags: list, csv, input, formatting, tuples

PYTHON - I would like to input the first two elements of data from the lines of a csv file. For example, 1,3,4 is the first line of the CSV file and I would like to make a dictionary of tuples where the first two numbers(1,3) as the key and the value is the third number(3).
So the output looks like this,

> > > {('1','3') : 4}

Comment: what language? what have you tried? why haven't you accepted answers to your other questions?

Comment: python.. because I didnt know I had to until now that you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the difficulty you face?.Post the code you tried.The follwoing should do the trick:

```
d={}
fp=open("csv","r")
for i in fp.readlines():
    d[(i[0],i[2])]=i[4]
```